# Listing the values of an enum from the Enum base class

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I'd like to know how to list the values of an enum when the Enum is passed in as a generic parameter. The below code is my attempt at this. My hope was that the loop in the ListReturnTypeValues method would cycle through the values Red, Blue, Green, but the code fails.

```
    public enum Colour
    {
        Red,
        Blue,
        Green
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ListReturnTypeValues(i => (Colour)i);
        }

        static void ListReturnTypeValues(Func<int, Enum> func)
        {
            foreach(var i in Enum.GetValues(func.Method.ReturnType))
            {
                //Cycle through Red, Blue, Green...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lets take a step back.... What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like `static void ListReturnTypeValues<T>() where T :Enum` Though without a more detailed explanation your question is fairly unclear to me

Comment: I just deleted my answer because like @TheGeneral mentioned, I want to know what you want to do? If you are always passing Colour as parameter then you dont need Enum at all just Pass Colour. You just want the names?

Comment: What I would like to achieve it to be able to cycle through the values of the Enum, no matter what particular Enum is passed in. Equally one should be able to pass in a function which returns Animal (for example), and still have it cycle through all of the values of the Animal Enum.

Comment: I probably should have made it clearer, but the reason it is as above is that this is a simplification of a similar case from my codebase.

Answer (score 1):

With inspiration from @TheGeneral's Comment, I was able to find a working solution:

```
    public enum Colour
    {
        Red,
        Blue,
        Green
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ListReturnTypeValues(i => (Colour)i);
        }

        static void ListReturnTypeValues<T>(Func<int, T> func) where T : Enum
        {
            foreach(var i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
            {
                //Cycle through Red, Blue, Green...
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Enum.GetNames(typeof(Colour))`

Comment: This is essentially what I want, except that I would like it to work generically such that I can pass any Enum into the Lamda expression and still have it cycle through the values.

Comment: Call The "func",Like this. "foreach (var i in Enum.GetNames(func(0).GetType()))"